# Extracting a URL parameter with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, query-string, url-parameters

I have a URL:

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382`

Edit: I should also not the url is stored in a variable and I want it to work something like this:

```
$(".videothumb a").live('click', function() {
        var URL = < do something to cut the string > 
        console.log(URL);
        return false;
    });
```

And I want to cut the URL starting from "=" and ending at "&" so I'll end up with a string like this: "JssO4oLBm2s".

I only know of the slice() function but I believe that only takes a number as beginning and end points.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I just updated.

Comment: did you try the answers posted below?

Comment: @KyleJoseph see me answer with fiddle demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.split()` will give a position based solution which will fail the order of parameters changes. Instead I think what you are looking for is the value of parameter called `v` for that you can use a simple regex like

```
'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382'.match('[?&]v=(.*?)(&|$)')[1]
```

Comment: @Krishna updated to fetch value of `v`

Comment: My url is stored in a variable so this doesn't work.

Comment: @KyleJoseph then use the variable like `myvar.match('[?&]v=(.*?)(&|$)')[1]`

Comment: I did and got this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null "

Comment: @KyleJoseph it looks like the url don't have the parameter `v=?`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382'
    .split('=')[1] // 'JssO4oLBm2s&list'
    .split('&')[0] // 'JssO4oLBm2s'
```

Or, if you want to be sure to get the `v` parameter,

```
var v, args = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382'.split("?")[1].split('&');
for(var i = args.length-1; i>=0; --i) {
    var data = args[i].split('=');
    if(data[0]==='v') {  v = data[1]; break;  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.split()`. Separated to 2 lines for clarity

```
var first = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382".split('=')[1]
var result = first.split('&')[0]; //result - JssO4oLBm2s
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v = 'JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382';

var vamploc = v.indexOf("&");

vstring = v.substr(0, vamploc);
```

You can play with the code a bit to refine it, but the general concepts work.

Answer (score 0):

use Regexp `(?:v=)(.+?)(?:&|$)`

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/5kU6d/)

```
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JssO4oLBm2s&list=PLGHJ4fVazTpYRZTEhqgurtSH6XlDMIEJM&shuffle=382".match('(?:v=)(.+?)(?:&|$)')[1]
```

---

Reference

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/